# Sidepanel with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement sidepanel with AngularJS, I am referring to the link here https://github.com/dpiccone/ng-pageslide and http://dpiccone.github.io/ng-pageslide/examples/.

Below is my HTML code and javascript, but I am not able to get it working. I don't see any error in the console.

```
    <html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/CarouselController.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/gsenv.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/thirdparty/angular-pageslide-directive.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: url(/resources/images/nyc.jpg) center top no-repeat;
    }

    html {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .ng-pageslide {
        background: #eee;
    }

    body.ng-pageslide-body-open::before {
        content: '.';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: 0.5;
        transition: opacity 1s;
        opacity: 0.5;
        pointer-events: all;
    }

    body.ng-pageslide-body-closed::before {
        transition: opacity 1s;
        content: '.';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        opacity: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
</style>
<div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl" class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="text-center text-primary">Welcome to ananta-gs dashboard</h1>
    <div style="height: 305px; width: 450px; margin:auto">
        <uib-carousel active="active" interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides">
            <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
                <img ng-src="/resources/images/cloud-home.jpg" style="margin:auto;">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <a href="#" ng-click='sendEnvName(slide.text)'>
                        <h3 class="carousel-caption text-primary center-block">
                            {{slide.text}}</h3>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </uib-slide>
        </uib-carousel>
    </div>
    <h3>Squeeze content</h3>
<a class="tiny button" href="" ng-click="toggle()">Open Sidebar</a>
<pageslide ps-open="checked" ps-side="left" ps-squeeze="true">
    <div style="padding:20px" id="demo-right">
        <h2>Hello Pageslide</h2>
        <p>Put here whatever you want</p>
        <a ng-click="toggle()" class="button">Close</a>
    </div>
</pageslide>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

below the jsfile

main.js

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngTable', 'pageslide-directive']);
```

CarouselController.js

```
/**
 * Created by Aj on 14-06-2016.
 */
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $http, dataShare, $uibModal) {
    $scope.myInterval = 5000;
    $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
    $scope.active = 0;
    var slides = $scope.slides = [];
    var currIndex = 0;

    $scope.sendEnvName = function (data) {
        dataShare.sendEnvDetails(data);

        window.location.href = "query/queryboard.html";
    }

    $scope.addSlide = function (envName) {
        slides.push({
            text: envName,
            id: currIndex++
        });
    };

    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/getEnvList")
        .success(function (data) {
            for (var i in data) {
                $scope.addSlide(data[i].envName);
            }
        })
        .error(function (errordata) {
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'error/ErrorModal.html',
                controller: 'ErrModalInstanceCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    error: function () {
                        console.log('error=' + errordata.errorMessage)
                        return errordata;
                    }
                }
            });


        });

    $scope.checked = false;
    $scope.size = '100px';

    $scope.toggle = function () {
        $scope.checked = !$scope.checked
    }

});

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ErrModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, error) {
    $scope.errormessage = error.errorMessage;
    $scope.stacktrace = error.stackTrace;

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.close('closed');
    };
});
```

Can some one please help me figure out where I am going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working here. I would suggest opening up your Dev tools. I have a feeling you are getting some Javascript errors in the console.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Svl4wkATqqMmhIJJvdoy

Here is part your controller, I took out 'dataShare', you might be missing the file on the page that has that service, take it out and it should work.

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $uibModal)
```

I didnt have all your files, so I did what I could.

Comment: I tried taking datashare out but it doesnt works, however when i explicitly marked ps-open="true", i could see the side panel on the page, so my suspicion is for some reason toggle functions is not called, any inputs why toggle function might not have been called ?

Comment: Did you look at the link? Its your code and its working. Did you open up the javascript console and look for errors? There is probably an error popping up that is stopping this from working.

Comment: if you mean javascript console in the browser, i did take a look, its all blank, i tried adding a console.log line in the toggle method it did not displayed.